# Accuracy in list of knn loop results different from actual knn accuracy

Tags: r, knn

I'm running a knn model in R and I'm trying to find the optimal k. To achieve this, I've constructed the following code.

```
suppressMessages(library(class))
set.seed(1)
Lag1 = rnorm(30)
Direction = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
X_train <- data.frame(Lag1[1:20])
X_test <- data.frame(Lag1[21:30])
Y_train <- data.frame(Direction[1:20])
Y_test <- data.frame(Direction[21:30])
knn_res <- rep(1,10)
for (i in 1:10) {
  predk <- knn(X_train, X_test, Y_train[,1], k=i)
  cm <- as.matrix(table(predk, Y_test[,1]))
  knn_res[i] <- sum(diag(cm))/length(predk)
}

# which is most optimal
which.max(knn_res)

# looks like K = 1 is the most optimal
predk <- knn(X_train, X_test, Y_train[,1], k=1)
cm <- as.matrix(table(predk1, Y_test[,1]))
sum(diag(cm))/length(predk)
```

According to `which.max(knn_res)` my optimal k should be but when I run the exact code from the loop to print my confusion matrix, the accuracy getting returned does not match up with the accuracy in my `knn_res` list. `knn_res[1]` returns `0.5` while `sum(diag(cm))/length(predk)` returns `0.3`.

Where have I gone amiss? I feel like it's something in the way I'm adding to my `knn_res` list but I'm not sure what...

Comment: We cannot run your code because you do not provide `X_train, X_test, Y_train`

Comment: @G5W added to OP

Comment: Still does not work.  You have 5 train points, so you cannot use k>5.

Comment: @G5W edited, generated 30 random points after setting seed

Comment: Typo: `cm <- as.matrix(table(predk1, Y_test[,1]))`. Change `predk1` to `predk`

Comment: @R.Schifini good catch, thank you! Unfortunately, in my real data (which I can't post) I don't have a typo so this doesn't solve my issue. Is there anything else that may be causing that?

Comment: I ran your code and for k=1 the result was the same, but not for even values of k. Why? For an even number of neighbors, the voting result may change each execution if you have a tie (e.g. two 1 vs two 0 knn will throw a dice).